# How do I use the autoform update form with flowrouter in Meteor?

Tags: forms, meteor, meteor-autoform, flow-router

I'm using flowrouter in my Meteor project, and I'm trying to figure out how to use it with autoform update. In other words, I'm trying to create a form to update my entity. This means that somehow the object needs to be passed to the template, but I'm not exactly sure how According to the [autoform docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#a-basic-update-form) you should do something like this;

```
<template name="updateBookForm">
  {{> quickForm collection="Books" doc=this id="updateBookForm" type="update"}}
</template>
```

but this example pertains to iron router. What additional code do I need to make the autoform update work with flow router ?

update ...

I tried the following

```
Template.UpdateItem.helpers({
    item: function () {
        var theItem = Items.findOne({_id: FlowRouter.current().params.itemId});
        console.log("the item:"+JSON.stringify(theItem));
        return theItem
    }
});
```

and in my template

```
             {{#with item}}
                <div>
                    {{> autoForm collection="Items" id="updateItemForm"  doc=item class= "new-item-form" type="update"}}
                </div>
             {{/with}}
```

but I'm still getting mothing ...

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't know what "this" is; it needs to be a chunk of JSON from your db. typically, i wrap the autoforms like this:

```
{{#with getDocument}}
    {{> quickForm collection="Books" doc=this id="updateBookForm" type="update"}}
{{/with}}
```

... and define a corresponding helper in the JS:

```
getDocument() {
    return Books.findOne({isbn: '978-3-16-148410-0'});
}
```

i am using flow router, this isn't an iron-router specific use case.

Comment: ahh right, was missing the with .... I think that iron router works out of the box without the helper function, thanks

Comment: tried that approach but I still get nothing ... please see edits above

Comment: first thing i would try is "doc=this" instead of "doc=item". it also looks a little strange that you have collection="Items", though you're doing a find on "Meals". it's probably okay, but looks odd.

Comment: so it appears that generating the auto form does not work, but if I add the quickform fields it works ... not sure if this is by design or a bug